# Handling file parse and upload on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I'm parsing an Excel file to an array in JavaScript and I have a simple form with a file upload and check boxes. I'm adapting the code from elsewhere and it runs perfectly as expected immediately on file upload, but I want it to handle the file on clicking submit, not on addEventListener for "change". How can I alter this JavaScript / jQuery so that it executes the handleFile in the same way it does now, but on the form submit click.

I tried multiple methods like

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", handleFile(oFileIn));
```

And encapsulating everything beneath setup in:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){ 
    var oFileIn; ...
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.12.6/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formid" action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <label><input id="inputX1" type="checkbox" name="x1" value="x1">x1</label><br>
          <label><input id="inputX2" type="checkbox" name="x2" value="x2">x2</label><br>
          <label><input id="inputX3" type="checkbox" name="x3" value="x3">x3</label><br>
          <label><input id="inputX4" type="checkbox" name="x4" value="x4">x4</label><br>
          <input id="fileid" type="file" name="filename" />
          <input id="submit" type="button" value="submit"/> 
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setup();
});

function setup() {
    var oFileIn;

    $(function() {
        oFileIn = document.getElementById('fileid');
        if(oFileIn.addEventListener) {
            oFileIn.addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);
        }
    });

    var rABS = true;
    function handleFile(e) {
      var files = e.target.files, f = files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        if(!rABS) data = new Uint8Array(data);
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: rABS ? 'binary' : 'array'});
        // DO STUFF WITH THE FILE HERE AND CHECK BOXES HERE
```

Comment: do you expect to submit the file to a server of some sort? What do you expect to happen on form submit? That usually means sending a request to a server and sending the user to another page. Do you mean you just want the file action to happen on a button click, not necessarily a submit action?

Comment: on submit the array being downloaded as a text file, that's working properly as well. It can be just on any button click, doesn't have to specifically be submit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So if you want to just load the data on a button click all you really need to do is put a click listener on your button instead of a change event on your file input.

Your attempt was close but since we can use the ID of the file input, there is no need to pass anything into `handleFile()`

I also put in a check to make sure a file is actually there before we go ahead and read it.

Here's an example using jQuery for you

```
function setup() {
    $("#submit").on("click", handleFile);

    var rABS = true;
    function handleFile() {
        var files = $("#fileid").prop("files");
        if(files.length === 0){
            alert("Please select a file first");
            return;
        }
        var f = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            //continue on with data
        }
        reader.readAsText(f);
    }
}
```